# How can i split datetime into different parts?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a column in my database named `created_at` (I am using laravel 5.2).Its value is something like this: `2016-10-01 01:22:13` .I want to split this date time in Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second.

I can go with below approach for just date have `2016-10-01` :

```
$resDate= explode('-', $resDate);
$year  = $resDate[0];
$month = $resDate[1];
$day   = $resDate[2];
```

But if date and time is altogether (`2016-10-01 01:22:13`) then how can i split it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php): Get info about given date formatted according to the specified format.

```
$date = '2016-10-01 01:22:13';
$split = date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d h:i:s', $date);

var_dump($split['year']); 
// outputs year from the string, 
//Similarly `$split['month']` will produce month name and so on.
```

Comment: it should be `date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d h:i:s', $date);`

Comment: Yup, Updated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

As per the data that you have in the DB you can concert the date to `strtotime()` and then format it as you required.

**Example:**

```
$date = 2016-10-01 01:22:13
```

then you may perform the following actions

```
echo  $date_alone = date('d',strtotime($date)) // 01
```

Like wise you can fetch all the data that you have based on the codes given below

`d` - Date

`m` - month

`Y` - Year

`H` - Hour

`i` - Minutes

`s` - Seconds

Below you can follow it for the reference purpose.

### Date and time formatting with PHP

2008-02-07 16:45:58 (Consider it as Example)

For those of you that are not genius enjoying themselves by calculating big integer time, I will reveal the mystery of how we can format dates and time. We will begin with dates formatting. It is done using date() function. It accepts two parameters. Format string and time as integer. We will use time() for current time integer. Let's see some examples.

```
echo date("d-m-y", time());     // 07-02-08
```

The dash between the characters in the format string above is exactly what the output is going to be separated with.

```
echo date("D j/n/Y", time());     // Thu 7/2/2008
```

The dash here is replaced with forward slash.

```
echo date("jS of F Y", time());     // 7th of February 2008
```

We can use any character we want here, just keep in mind that if it has a special meaning it has to be escaped. And just to be sure that there are no mistakes I suggest that you always escape every character you use.

```
echo date("d M y", time());     //07 Feb 08
```

Formatting the date using short representation for month names and short year.

```
echo date("l jS of F", time());     // Thursday 7th of February
```

Full day and month name with ordinal suffix for the day of the month.

Date format characters' legend by examples:

d - Numeric representation of a day, with leading zeros 01 through 31.

m - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros 01 through 12.

y - Numeric representation of a year, two digits.

D - Textual representation of a day, three letters Mon through Sun.

j - Numeric representation of a day, without leading zeros 1 through 31.

n - Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros 1 through 12.

Y - Numeric representation of a year, four digits.

S - English ordinal suffix for the day of the month. Consist of 2 characters st, nd, rd or th.

F - Textual representation of a month, January through December.

M - Textual representation of a month, three letters Jan through Dec.

l textual representation of the day of the week Sunday through Saturday.
Now we move on to our next task which is time formatting. We are still going to use the same date() function, but with different format characters.

```
echo date("G:i:s", time());     //16:45:58
```

Working with time is a little bit simpler, because there is only one way to represent minutes and seconds.

```
echo date("H:i:s", time());    //16:45:58
```

Despite of the very few options for minutes and seconds formats we have a lot of hour formatting styles. This one represents hours with leading zeroes 0 through 23.

```
echo date("g:i a.", time());     //4:45 pm.
```

Comment: For more info refer https://www.phpjabbers.com/date-and-time-formatting-with-php-php28.html

Comment: Forgot to add reference since i was adding the solution over to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For all i know there isn't a function that fills your datetime value parts into an array in php. You can create your own function to split your datetime value into an array.

Example:

```
function dateTimeToArray($myDateTime)
{
    $dateTime = new DateTime($myDateTime);

    $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
    $time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');

    $dateTimeArray = array_merge(explode('-', $date), explode(':', $time));

    return $dateTimeArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel models you have datetime fields as Carbon object.

So you can simply call ->toDateString() if a date is needed

```
$modelObject->created_at->toDateString();
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Also you can access directly to all values of the date.
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

```
$year  = $modelObject->created_at->year;
$month = $modelObject->created_at->month;
$day   = $modelObject->created_at->day;
```